# java passing string to file writer makes jumble in file created

Tags: java, string, filewriter

Shouldnt be a hard one!

I have a jfilechooser and store the selected file path as a string

```
String filepath; 
filepath= openFile.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

I can display this as a label on gui doing such and works fine:

```
 filepathlabel.setText(""+filepath.toString());
```

and then adding the filepathlabel to content pane.

My question
I have a file writer
i can write to the file, such as i like...
But when i pass the filepath sting to the filewriter
In the text file created by the file writer it shows like this inside:

```
javax.swing.JLabel[,213,288,439x16,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@58ae42b4,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=C:\Users\shane\Documents\TWITCH\kim.gif,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

now in the mix of this, it does show the filepath, but how can i tidy all this surrounding matter out?

i am passing the string like this:

```
 printwriter.println(filepath);
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `sysout`ing your path and see if it comes out normal

Comment: Aren't you passing the `JLabel` instance to the writer instead of the path `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome @Shane.

What gets written to the file is the `toString()` value of `javax.swing.JLabel` object not the value of JLabel object. Rather call the `getText()` of JLabel object and write that String value to the file.

*As a side note:*

`filepathlabel.setText(""+filepath.toString());` is not the correct way to do this. Please change it to `filepathlabel.setText(filepath);` As `filepath` is already a String